# Анимация точек (dots) в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

Ребята, всем привет! Подскажите, как сделать кастомную анимацию перехода для точек (dots) в слайдере, чтобы оно плавно линией переходило на другой активный слайд. Буду благодарен за подсказку!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Типа того?

```js
let checked = null;
let changer = null;
let clickStopper = false;

const dotChanger = (event) => {
  if (clickStopper) return false;
  else clickStopper = true;
  let target = event.target;
  changer.style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible');
  if (checked.offsetLeft < target.offsetLeft) 
    changer.style.setProperty('width', `${target.offsetLeft - checked.offsetLeft + checked.offsetWidth}px`);
  else {
    changer.style.setProperty('left', `${target.offsetLeft}px`);
    changer.style.setProperty('width', `${checked.offsetLeft - target.offsetLeft + target.offsetWidth}px`);
  };
  setTimeout(()=>{
    if (checked.offsetLeft < target.offsetLeft) changer.style.setProperty('left', `${target.offsetLeft}px`);
    changer.style.removeProperty('width');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      changer.style.removeProperty('visibility');
      checked = target;
      clickStopper = false;
    }, 500);
  }, 500)
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('.slider__dots__dot')].forEach(dot=>{
  dot.addEventListener('click', dotChanger);
});
checked = document.querySelector('.slider__dots__dot:checked');
changer = document.querySelector('.slider__dots__changer');
changer.style.setProperty('left', `${checked.offsetLeft}px`);
```

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.slider__dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: .5rem;
}
.slider__dots__dot {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background: white;
  margin: .5rem;
  transition: background .5s .5s ease-out;
}
.slider__dots__dot:active, .slider__dots__dot:checked {
  background: purple;
}
.slider__dots__changer {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background: purple;
  transition: left .5s ease-out, width .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slider__dots'>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot'>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot'>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot' checked>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot'>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot'>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot'>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot'>
    <input type='radio' name='slider1' class='slider__dots__dot'>
    <div id='slider1__changer' class='slider__dots__changer'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.slick__slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  appendDots: $(".slick__nav")
});
```

```css
.slick__nav {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slick-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-dots button {
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: purple;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 1px;
  transition: width .2s linear;
}

.slick-active {
  text-align: center;
}


.slick-active button{
  width: 60px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="slick">
  <div class="slick__slider">
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="slick__slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick__nav"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почти так, но анимацию перехода именно. Чтобы все были круглые а переход был как у Вас активный элемент.

Comment: @w3cwhy сожалею, но я вас не понимаю.